# Reactjs seting backgroundImage

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Ok this has been bugging me for a while ,after searching alot in the web  I found that this should work in index.css

```css
body {
    background-image: url(../src/components/images/photo.jpeg) no-repeat center center 
    fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

However it apparently doenst work .Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: How exactly is this question related to React?

Comment: Well I am trying to have  a background-Image as full size cover in ReactJs. maybe  there is a better way like <BackgroundImage/> in React-Native.Thats why i tagged it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using long-hand syntax, and this doesn't support other values except url. So, just use:

```
background-image: url(../src/components/images/photo.jpeg)
```

Further, a better approach to use images from public folder, so you can use like this:

```
background-image: url(/images/photo.jpeg)
```

---

To add other values, use:

```
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

---

To use short-hand syntax, use:

```
background: url(/images/photo.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Comment: I tryed your approach aswell, no changes in my background still empty screen.I only need to add it to index.css and then it should work right?

Comment: You can use my approach from anywhere but the style should be binding in the component.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. I want my whole body to have this background Image, do I need to set anything in my App.js? doesnt setting body with your approach on index.css cover it?

Comment: be sure to use width and height to 100%

Comment: I finally figured it out.I had imported this line to my index.js file                          
            import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'; and this was messing with my css

Answer (score 0):

try using style

```
<body
  style={{
    backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
  }}
></body>
```